# Navigating user to different site and server under one URL

Tags: hosting

I have a website, say a warehouse management system, which is accessible via `whmgt.example.com`.

Then there are multiple customers: cust A, B and C who will use this system but separately. Everyone hosts this system on their own server, which I manage for them. The reason why we need to host separately is each customer's system is slightly different from one another (e.g. algorithms, features, customization, etc.) so they will run on different versions.

Is it possible to make everyone access this system via `whmgt.example.com` and have their own paths to their server? E.g. `whmgt.example.com/CustA/`, `whmgt.example.com/CustB/` where `/CustA/` will load website from Customer A's server.

How can I achieve this? Using load balancer, CDN or else?

Please let me know if I need to provide more information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible when you use sub domains.

Load balancing is separate concept which use to divide loads or request.But your requirement is not a load balancing.

Answer (score 0):

It first sounds like each customer is running this application on their own server, i.e. on their own premises, but after some more explanation it sounds everything is running at one hosting location.

In the latter case it's not a problem to do it like you suggest, i.e. using a subdirectory for each customer. I would recommend using `haproxy` as the frontend reverse proxy, it can also handle the SSL for https and talk e.g. plain http to each customer's backend server (or also https).

Use an ACL that matches the path prefix, and choose the backend according to the ACLs matched. Something like:

```
frontend https
    bind :443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/ssl/whmgt.example.com.pem
    acl CustA path_beg /CustA/
    acl CustB path_beg /CustB/

    use_backend custa if CustA
    use_backend custb if CustB
    default_backend fallthru

backend custa
    server custa_1 192.168.0.2:80

backend custb
    server custb_1 192.168.0.3:80

backend fallthru
    server localhost:80
```

The fallthru can be used to give a warning that the path is wrong or whatever.